# Diff highlighting in Intellij for Golang test assertions

Tags: go, intellij-idea, goland

Does anybody know how to print differences of a e.g. struct so that Intellij understands it, specifically, in a test?

For example, when using Hamcrest or Mockito in Java, if an assertion fails, these libraries print in a way that Intellij can understand it and when you click on the assertion error message, Intellij opens a comparison window where I can see the diff very easily with nice highlighting.

Any libraries out there supporting this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the result won´t be as pretty as the examples you mention but you could try using [go-spew](https://github.com/davecgh/go-spew) or [godebug](https://github.com/kylelemons/godebug) in your tests to print out the differences in failure cases. You won't get the compare pop-up but you will be able to easily identify mismatches

Answer (score 0):

GoLand (or IntelliJ IDEA with Go plugin) supports several libraries at the moment with *Click to see difference* feature:

- Testify assertions (github.com/stretchr/testify/assert).

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "testing"
)

func TestSomething(t *testing.T) {
    assert.Equal(t, 1234, 123, "they should be equal")
}
```

- gocheck (gopkg.in/check.v1).

```golang
package main

import (
    "testing"

    . "gopkg.in/check.v1"
)

// Hook up gocheck into the "go test" runner.
func Test(t *testing.T) { TestingT(t) }

type MySuite struct{}

var _ = Suite(&MySuite{})

func (s *MySuite) TestHelloWorld(c *C) {
    c.Assert(42, Equals, "42")
}
```